# Словосочетание «русско- и англоязычные издания»

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли именно такое написание двух сложных прилагательных с общим корнем при их перечислении. Нужен ли дефис?

Answer (score 2):

Все верно. Дефис применяется при записи конструкций с однородными членами, имеющими общий конечный элемент, если все члены, кроме последнего, представлены только начальными элементами; такой дефис называют «висячим».Напр.: шарико- и роликоподшипники; лит- и изокружки; кино-, теле- и видеофильмы;

См.: Академический справочник.